# Autowire bean in spring boot return null?

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp

I have created a request call to another server using OkHttp and I using `Autowired` to inject a `bean` to it seem not working.

This is my configuration bean

```java
@Configurable
public class HttpConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }
}
```

This is my class to call the request

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class GraphQLImpl  {

    @Autowired
    public OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

    public List<Product> getProducts( int countryId, String URL, String token, List<String> articleIds) {
        DefaultGraphQLClient graphQLClient = new DefaultGraphQLClient(URL);
        GraphQLResponse response = graphQLClient.executeQuery(QueryUtils.getProductsQuery(articleIds, PartitionUtil.getReadPartition(token), countryId), new HashMap<>(), "", (url, headers, body) -> {
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                    .url(url)
                    .post(RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown"), body))
                    .build();
                try {
                    Response responseOkHttp = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                    return new HttpResponse(responseOkHttp.code(), responseOkHttp.body().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                }
                return new HttpResponse(404, "Can't find product");
            }
        );
        return response.extractValueAsObject("data.products[*]", new TypeRef<List<Product>>() {
        });
    }

}
```

When I check `okHttpClient`, It returns `null` inside the method? Why is that? I do I fix it?

Comment: You didn't show where you're _using_ `GraphQLImpl`.

Comment: GraphQLImpl graphQLImpl = new GraphQLImpl(); and then use the method inside it.

Answer (score 2):

In your `HttpConfiguration` class, you are using `@Configurable` and that is for creating objects with `new` keyword to be `@Autowired`. Basically `@Configurable` with AspectJ compile-time weaving to inject your objects. This requires code configuration. However, for easy approach I suggest you to use `@Configuration` annotation for `HttpConfiguration` class.

You will get further information via the below mentioned previously posted question.

[Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Hope this solves your problem!